# Разбивка жестких дисков под систему виртуализации

Tags: сервер, vmware, виртуализация

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить в данной ситуации. Имеется новый серевер HP Proliant ML350 g6, в нем стоит два жестких диска объемом по 300 гигов, система в них не установлена: они пустые. На этом физическов серваке будет установленно два виртуальных сервера. Операционная система будет использована Microsoft SBS 2011 Standart и для виртуализации серверов VMware ESxi.

Первый виртуальный сервер будет использоваться как централизованная база пользователей, контроль доступа к бухгалтерским базам, централизованное управление антивиуссными приложениями, корпоротивная почта с доступом во внешнию сеть и система резервного копирования.

Второй виртуальный сервер будет использоваться как файловое хранилище с максимальнй защитой от вирусной активности и системой резервного копирования критических данных.

Задача заключается в следующем.

Как правильно распределить оба места жестких дисков по разделам для физического сервера и для двух виртуальных серверов?

Answer (score 2):

В данной ситуации:

во первых - обновите прошивку контроллера дисков. насколько я знаю, тут стоит SAS контроллер.

во вторых - скачайте [СПЕЦИАЛЬНУЮ версию гипервизора ESXi](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPVM09) для хюлетпакардовских серверов. По идее она работает стабильнее чем общая.

в третьих - объедините диски в RAID (mirror). Ваши оба диска станут как один, **объём уменьшится в два раза**, но вероятность потери данных **значительно снизится**.

Затем установите ESXi. При установке диск будет разбит на системный раздел ESXi и раздел с DATASTORE для хранения виртуальных машин. **Больше разбивать не надо**.

Потом установите себе на управляющий компьютер консоль управления и подключитесь по сети к вашему серверу.

Настройте внутреннюю и внешнюю сеть. Можно сделать так, что один сетевой адаптер будет чисто для управления, а второй - для работы. Можно наоборот, настроить две сети - одну внутрь офиса, другую - в интернет. Можно использовать VLANы.

Пропишите лицензию (бесплатная заказывается на сайте VMWare)

Загрузите в datastore готовые образы виртуальных машин или создайте чистые ВМ и установите на них систему. Исходя из системных требований Microsoft SBS, на виртуальную машину вам надо будет выделить 120 GB места.

Вот вроде и всё.